# Bootstrap CSS override - css attributes disappearing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am creating a BootStrap 2.3.2 website. I need to over-ride some CSS, such as the header colors, so I created a new CSS file (actually, I created a new LESS file, and IT created a new CSS file) called theme.css. This is an ASP.NET MVC project, so I added that to the bundle.config, and when I run the project, I view the page source, and can see that the theme.css is correctly loading AFTER the bootstrap.css, i.e.:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/BackOffice/Content/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Here is the CSS in theme.css. It should change the background color of the nav bar.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
  background-color: #ff7400;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff7400, ##FF9640);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: ##FF9640;
}
```

It is not working. So I fire up "Firebug" in FF, and examine the CSS attached to the element. What I see is this:

```
body .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #FF7400;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

As you can see, the **background-image** and **border-color** properties are now ***missing***. I can see **background-color** property is linked to theme.css properly, and nothing is showing up as "struck-through" which is how FireBug shows that a property has been over-ridden. It's just "not there".

When I go into the CSS tab in FireBug and examine the theme.css file, again, those two properties are missing. Just plain "gone". As if they never existed.

I've checked and rechecked my files. Other properties in the theme.css file are there - some are, some aren't...

What the heck? How can an imported *.css file be missing properties?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the CSS from FireBug. As you can see, the properties are actually missing from theme.css. http://i.imgur.com/UyYCIwW.png

Comment: I also tried adding !important to the properties. Doesn't matter, they are still missing when I import the css, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra # on ##FF9640. Change it to #FF9640 in both css rules and it should work.

Comment: OMG thank you... been staring at that for the past hour, and it was just not registering in my brain... :(